# Geometric mean of prime gaps?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, average, prime-gaps

The arithmetic mean of prime gaps around $x$ is $\ln(x)$.
What is the geometric mean of prime gaps around $x$ ?

Does that strongly depend on the conjectures about the smallest and largest gap such as Cramer's conjecture or the twin prime conjecture ?

Comment: Why the geometric average?

Comment: Why not ? A very often used average. It would give some insight.

Comment: ...the arithmetic one is always the first that comes to my mind, so I just wondered why you expect more insight from "geometrical" point of view...

Comment: @draks: Looking at things from two sides gives more insight than just one viewpoint.

Comment: @MvG ok; _at_mick +1...

Comment: what do you mean by "around x"?

Comment: do you mean "up to x"?

Comment: I would imagine that this, as you ask, does depend strongly on certain unknown properties of the primes - the arithmetic mean is easy because we sum up a lot of differences and the sum "telescopes" - so if we average $n$ consecutive differences, the average is $\frac{p_{m+n}-p_m}n$ - which relies on a more global property of prime numbers, given by the prime number theorem. The geometric mean won't telescope and tells more about the distribution of prime gaps - e.g. if gaps tend to be either really small or really big, the geometric mean will be dragged down far from the arithmetic mean.

Comment: would this Q be better: if g- is the gap before a prime p, and g+ the gap after p, can we say anything about g-/g+?

Comment: Of course we have by the AM-GM inequality that the geometric mean is smaller.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[In 1976 Gallagher](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FMTK%2FMTK23_01%2FS0025579300016442a.pdf&code=d846fb78292da74c9a5cdd4ecca8b84c) proved, under the assumption of a uniform version of the Hardy-Littlewood $k$-tuples conjecture, that for any fixed $\lambda>0$ and integer $k$ $$\#\{\text{ integers } x\leq X\ :\  \pi(x+\lambda \log x)-\pi(x)=k\}\sim e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}X,$$ that is it follows a [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

Since the waiting times for a Poisson distribution is an [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), Gallagher's work also yields (on the assumption of a uniform Hardy-Littlewood conjecture) that for fixed $\alpha,\beta$ $$\frac{1}{\pi(x)}\#\{n\leq \pi(x):\ g_n\in \left(\alpha \log x, \beta \log x\right)\}\sim \int_\alpha^\beta e^{-t}.$$ Thus the geometric mean of the $g_n$ asymptotically will equal $$\exp\left(\frac{1}{\pi(x)}\sum_{n\leq \pi(x)} \log (g_n)\right)\sim \exp\left(\log \log x+\int_0^\infty \log t e^{-t}dt\right).$$
Since $\int_0^\infty \log t e^{-t}dt=-\gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), and we find that the geometric mean is

> $$\sim e^{-\gamma}\log x.$$

Comment: Would like to see the actual proof (free).

Answer (score 8):

I thought Hardy-Littlewood might come into it.
Here is some numerical data following Erics great answer:
[image: x-axis: N ; y-axis: Geometric mean of the first 10000 prime gaps following $10^N$ divided by $\ln 10^N$]

x-axis: N

y-axis: Geometric mean of the first 10000 prime gaps following $10^N$ divided by $\ln 10^N$.

$e^{-\gamma} \approx 0.56146$.

Comment: This is fantastic. I was wondering why my numerical data seemed a little off - I did not take $N$ to be anywhere near large enough!

Comment: It does converge rather slow(ly?). The number of gaps for a given size has to be large as well. Looking at the graph, 10000 gaps is not enough to get a very accurate result, but the trend is clearly visible.