# Geometric mean of prime twin gaps?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, proof-writing, means

This question is an analogue of [Geometric mean of prime gaps?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1261272/geometric-mean-of-prime-gaps)

Where primes have been replaced by prime twins.

### Eric's answer :

[In 1976 Gallagher](http://journals.cambridge.org/download.php?file=%2FMTK%2FMTK23_01%2FS0025579300016442a.pdf&code=d846fb78292da74c9a5cdd4ecca8b84c) proved, under the assumption of a uniform version of the Hardy-Littlewood $k$-tuples conjecture, that for any fixed $\lambda>0$ and integer $k$ $$\#\{\text{ integers } x\leq X\ :t\  \pi(x+\lambda \log x)-\pi(x)=k\}\sim e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}X,$$ that is it follows a [Poisson distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution).

Since the waiting times for a Poisson distribution is an [exponential distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_distribution), Gallagher's work also yields (on the assumption of a uniform Hardy-Littlewood conjecture) that for fixed $\alpha,\beta$ $$\frac{1}{\pi(x)}\#\{n\leq \pi(x):\ g_n\in \left(\alpha \log x, \beta \log x\right)\}\sim \int_\alpha^\beta e^{-t}.$$ Thus the geometric mean of the $g_n$ asymptotically will equal $$\exp\left(\frac{1}{\pi(x)}\sum_{n\leq \pi(x)} \log (g_n)\right)\sim \exp\left(\log \log x+\int_0^\infty \log t e^{-t}dt\right).$$
Since $\int_0^\infty \log t e^{-t}dt=-\gamma$ where $\gamma$ is the [Euler-Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), and we find that the geometric mean is

> $$\sim e^{-\gamma}\log x.$$

---

But there is more.

I asked the same question to my mentor tommy1729.

He reached the same conclusion but a dubious method ?? He referred to Mertens' product.
( Mertens' third theorem about $\Pi_p (1-1/p)$ , see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens'_theorems )

So inspired by that , i wonder about the geometric mean and if it relates - analogue to Mertens' product - with an infinite product over odd primes such as $ 0,5 $ $ \Pi_p ( 1 - 2/p )$ , the prime twins constant or similar.

Ofcourse we assume the AM to be $C ln(x)^2$.
I guess we might also need an analogue of hardy-littlewood or something. What we actually need is an issue of " inverse mathematics " i guess.

But apart from theorems based on assumptions , there is also supportive data to be collected.

Imho this also calls for a generalization , but it is probably best to settle the above first.