# What's the typical role of the constant $e^{-\gamma}$?

Tags: constants, euler-mascheroni-constant, big-picture

I often encounter this constant in my research, but I wonder what typical roles does it play in other areas of mathematics? Wikipedia mentions probability theory but nothing exact.

Also, I am interested to know best keywords to search about this constant.

Comment: It appears in Mertens' third theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens%27_theorems

Answer (score 1):

This constant appears in Weierstrass factorization of $\Gamma(s)$:

$$
{1\over\Gamma(s)}=se^{\gamma s}\prod_{k\ge1}\left(1+\frac sk\right)e^{-s/k}
$$

and also in Mertens' formula:

$$
\prod_{p\le x}\left(1-\frac1p\right)={e^{-\gamma}\over\log x}\left[1+\mathcal O\left(1\over\log x\right)\right]
$$

Mertens' formula accounts for most appearance of $e^\gamma$ in number theory. For instance, it can be used to deduce the minimal order of Euler's totient function:

$$
\liminf_{n\to\infty}{\varphi(n)\log\log n\over n}=e^{-\gamma}
$$

and the maximal order for divisor sum function (aka Gronwall's theorem):

$$
\limsup_{n\to\infty}{\sigma(n)\over n\log\log n}=e^\gamma
$$

Answer (score 1):

*Number theory*: The [geometric mean of prime numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1277580/398708) around $n$, is approximately $\color{red}{e^{-\gamma}}\log n$.

*Probability*: If $u_1=$ random real number in $(0,1)$, and $u_k=$ random real number in $(0,u_{k-1})$, then the [probability](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4643289/398708) that $\sum_{k=1}^\infty u_k>1$, is $1-\color{red}{e^{-\gamma}}$.

(To find more, you can try putting $e^{-\gamma}$ in the search bar here on MSE, or at [approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/).)

Comment: What is "random real number"? I asked this question but it was deleted: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4716621/2513